# GNU ls long listing without permissions/mode bit

Tags: permissions, ls

Is it possible to make GNU ls omit permissions/mode bits in long listing? If not, is there an alternative, practical and commonly available program that is more flexible?

Comment: Why do you need this? Or, to put it differently, what is your use case?

Comment: Interactive use in narrow terminals (for example low resolution, or narrow display). Too much information is also annoying sometimes.

Piping to awk, sed et al is not really practical for interactive use. Sure, I could build little script files and so on, but I was interested in something native.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Upvoted. Unfortunately, I don't think `ls` has this kind of flexibility builtin. Though you could submit a wishlist bug. But I doubt that sort of functionality is a priority for the GNU project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ls -got --color=yes | cut -b 1,13-128
```

or this:

```
ls -l | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'
```

Comment: The second command truncates file names with spaces and information about symlinks.